# OpenTok / ToxBox: Keep the API Key secret?

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I'm using the OpenTok .js API to build a web app.

The TokBox "Security Best Practices" doc (https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/security/#best-practices) says "Keep the API key and secret private and secure"

I can keep the API "secret" out of the browser app, but as far as I can tell, the API *Key* has to be available to the browser, in order to make calls to OT.initSession().

Am I missing something, or is the TokBox documentation just misleading?

Answer (score 3):

Manik here from the OpenTok team.

You are correct, the API Key will be available on the client side (browser, mobile device, etc) as expected. This is not an issue because you need the API Key & API Secret combination to be able to create sessions, generate tokens, etc.

For security purposes, you should not expose the combination of API Key and API Secret.

Comment: you should just not expose the API Secret (e.g. it's secret) but API Key is public so can be exposed